# C# Tokenizer using Regex - Stop it looking miles ahead

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to create a compiler for a custom programming language, and I have done so in Java. However for good reasons I wanted to port it to native code, C# was my choice. The problem I am facing is that when I am matching with regular expressions, the matcher is looking through the entire source code file and not the start.

Example of source code:

```
namespace CrazyRedd{
    class Test{
        public function main(string[] args){
            System.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Output (format is tokenValue + " | " + tokenType):

```
namespace | KEYWORD
class | KEYWORD
function | KEYWORD
 | STR_LITERAL
 | STR_LITERAL
public | IDENTIFIER
Hello | IDENTIFIER
. | SYMBOL
; | SYMBOL
( | SYMBOL
( | SYMBOL
Systemprintln | IDENTIFIER
) | SYMBOL
) | SYMBOL
World | IDENTIFIER
[ | SYMBOL
] | SYMBOL
string | BUILT_IN_TYPE
main | IDENTIFIER
{ | SYMBOL
CrazyRedd | IDENTIFIER
{ | SYMBOL
Test | IDENTIFIER
{ | SYMBOL
args | IDENTIFIER
} | SYMBOL
} | SYMBOL
} | SYMBOL
```

The method for getting the next token is:

```
    public Token nextToken()
    {
        str = str.Trim();
        if (pushBack)
        {
            pushBack = false;
            return lastToken;
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            return (lastToken=new Token("", TokenType.EMPTY));
        }
        foreach(TokenData tokenData in tokenDatas)
        {
            Match matcher = Regex.Match(str, tokenData.getPattern(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (matcher.Success)
            {
                string token = matcher.Value.Trim();
                Regex replacer = new Regex(Regex.Escape(token));
                str = replacer.Replace(str,"",1);
                if (tokenData.getType() == TokenType.STR_LITERAL)
                {
                    return (lastToken = new Token(token.Substring(1, token.Length - 1),
                        TokenType.STR_LITERAL));
                }
                else
                {
                    return (lastToken = new Token(token, tokenData.getType()));
                }
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Fatal Error: Could not compile: "+str);
    }
```

Finally, the following is the method that inits the Tokenizer:

```
public void init()
        {
            string[] keys = { "if", "else", "namespace", "class", "function" };
            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                tokenDatas.Add(new TokenData(key + "\\s", TokenType.KEYWORD));
            }
            string[] types = { "int", "byte", "char", "string", "bool", "const" };
            foreach (string type in types)
            {
                tokenDatas.Add(new TokenData(type + "\\s", TokenType.BUILT_IN_TYPE));
            }
            tokenDatas.Add(new TokenData("(-)?[0-9]+", TokenType.INT_LITERAL));
            tokenDatas.Add(new TokenData("\"*\"", TokenType.STR_LITERAL));
            tokenDatas.Add(new TokenData("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\\s", TokenType.IDENTIFIER));
            string[] syms = { "\\.", "\\,", "\\;", "\\(", "\\)", "\\[", "\\]", "\\{", "\\}" };
            foreach (string sym in syms)
            {
                tokenDatas.Add(new TokenData(sym, TokenType.SYMBOL));
            }
            string[] ops = { "\\+", "\\-", "\\*", "/", "%", "=", "\\+=", "-=", "\\*=", "/=", "%=" };
            foreach (string op in ops)
            {
                tokenDatas.Add(new TokenData(op, TokenType.OPERATOR));
            }
            string[] coms = { "<", ">", "<=", ">=", "==", "!=" };
            foreach (string com in coms)
            {
                tokenDatas.Add(new TokenData(com, TokenType.COMPARATOR));
            }
        }
```

What I need to know is that what is causing the Tokenizer to spit out the Tokens in the wrong order.

Comment: *"However for good reasons I wanted to port it to native code, C# was my choice"* You understand C# isn't native right? Why not use some sort of AST tool like ANTLR instead of regex?

Comment: You should try to use [Irony](https://irony.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just glancing at your code, this seems  to be causing your problem.

Each call to nextToken()

```
foreach(TokenData tokenData in tokenDatas)
{
   Match matcher = Regex.Match(str, tokenData.getPattern(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   if (matcher.Success)
       ...
}
```

causes this loop, where the Match function is given a new pattern
for each new `tokenData`.
Like all engines this starts the match check at position 0.

The reason its out of order is because it is matching whatever order the
regex patterns happen to be in *no matter where* the match occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however in the end my solution was to use `if (matcher.Success && matcher.Index == 0)`.

Comment: @CrazyRedd - Yep, that's more in line with a tokenizer. I see why you're using regex (some have `\s+)`, but it's not really necessary as it can be thrown away. I'm going to give some simple suggestions. If I had your full code, I'd try it out for you. But, it's better you do it.

Comment: @CrazyRedd - Suggestions:  I'm not really a C# programmer, so some of this may be off. First, add a new member to TokenData class. This will be created in the constructor. `tokRX = new Regex("\\G"+_passed in regex string_, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` where the `getPattern()` function returns a reference to it. So the body of  `foreach(TokenData tokenData in tokenDatas)` becomes: Match matcher = tokenData.getPattern().Match( str, offset); if (matcher.Success) { offset += matcher.Length; if ( offset >= str.Length ) bReachedEnd = true; _Process the token_ }.

Comment: @CrazyRedd - Doing it this way eliminates the need to rewrite the `str` each time (ie. stripping the token). And, by using `\G` anchor, will only match at the `offset` position, eliminating the repetitive matching to the end of the string (and the check for Index == 0). This is more in line with how a character based tokenizer would do it. Hope this helps. As a bonus, the regex are only compiled once, and only need to use a single try/catch at the time of construction.